# How to numerically simulate random quantum circuit?

Tags: quantum-information, computational-physics, phase-transition, quantum-computer

Recent years, measurement induced phase transition has been widely studied with random quantum circuit model https://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.7.031016 . I know little about quantum information theory. My question is that how can we efficiently simulate random quantum circuit numerically?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Many numerics are done with Clifford circuits, which can be very efficiently simulated.

Comment: are there any materials about clifford circuit and its simulation for beginners?

Comment: You can check out the first section of [Statistical mechanics of quantum error correcting codes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.03822.pdf) for a simple introduction and [Improved Simulation of Stabilizer Circuits](https://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/chp6.pdf) for an introduction to one of the algorithms to implement it. There are more details in the [Introduction to Quantum Information Science II Lecture Notes](https://www.scottaaronson.com/qisii.pdf).